# Send and recive message or notification in my app in different devices through my aap

Tags: java, android

I want to make an app in android in which i send a message or notification and it will automatically send to all the users of my app or they will get notification like i want to say them your test will be tomorrow ...
kindly tell me the code of sending and receiving the message or notification all the users of my app

Comment: Use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).

Answer (score 0):

Check below links :

- [GCM Android developer tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)
- [GCM Example 1](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/)
- [GCM Example 2](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device, and also to receive messages from devices on the same connection.

Android App can receive the message from Google cloud messaging server (GCM) even if the app is not running via Intent broadcasting.

Thanks.